# What is the relationship between airflow.cfg and airflow_local_settings.py?

Tags: airflow

Both of these files seem to define configuration. What is the difference between the two?

- [airflow_local_settings.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/config_templates/airflow_local_settings.py)
- [airflow.cfg](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg)

Answer (score 2):

at the head of airflow_local_settings.py you can see

```
from airflow.configuration import conf
```

this line cause airflow to read airflow.cfg file

```
conf = initialize_config() # configuration.py
```